# Is there any existing software can achieve my Java data transmission encryption?

Tags: java, security

I recently built a J2SE chatting application, but I think I should take a consideration about data transmission encryption. But I cannot code it from scratch.

I don't know if there is a existing encryption application can help me to achieve the goal? The key point is: it should supprt Java application.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using SSL for this.  Java has built-in support for SSL via SSLSocketFactory:

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

...

SocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
Socket s = factory.createSocket( host, port );
```

From that point, use the socket just as you normally would.

Comment: SSL itself does not provide a solution to all security risks. For exemple, it would not authenticated any peer (aka one user can spoof another).

Comment: you can do mutual ssl really easily, then both sides need a cert. Its almost impossible to spoof

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called the Java API ;-)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136007.html

You might use the transport layer security (https and friends) or encrypt your data through JCA (Java cryptography architecture).